# switch statement C++ [default part]

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, while-loop, switch-statement, default

I'm writing a basic program about switch statement. The menu of 5 selections, if the use input invalid number, the user should be prompted again to make a selection (range is from 1-5). Here what I got so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Menu.h"
using namespace std;

void Menu::inputChoices()
{
    int choice;

    cout << "IHCC Computer Science Registration Menu" << endl;
    cout << "1. Welome to Computer Programming in C++" << endl;
    cout << "2. Welcome to Java Programming" << endl;
    cout << "3. Welcome to Android Programming" << endl;
    cout << "4. Welcome to iOS Programming" << endl;
    cout << "5. Exit" << endl;
    cout << "\nEnter your selection: " << endl;

    while ((choice = cin.get()) != EOF)
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
        case '1':
            cout << "Welcome to Computer Programming in C++" << endl;
            break;
        case '2':
            cout << "Welcome to Java Programming" << endl;
            break;
        case '3':
            cout << "Welcome to Android Programming" << endl;
            break;
        case '4':
            cout << "Welcome to iOS Programming" << endl;
            break;
        case '5':
            cout << "Exiting program" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid input. Re-Enter your selection: " << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

This project has 3 files, this is the source file. My problem is when I input a number is in the range (1-5), the default part of switch still also shows up. I just want show up my selection. Can anyone help me please! Thank you very much

Comment: Hello, if one of the answers helped you solve your problem, please check it as correct. If not, we can try to help you further.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are also getting the default value is because `cin.get()` is reading the newline character (10).

I don't think using `cin.get` makes sense here since entering something like `23987928` or `asdasf` will output a ton of lines... You should use `cin >> choice` and convert your cases into `int`s. Something like:

```
cin >> choice;
switch (choice)
{
    case 1:
        cout << "Welcome to Computer Programming in C++" << endl;
        break;
    // ...
    default:
        cout << "Invalid input. Re-Enter your selection: " << endl;
}
```

Comment: This will eat *any* `\n`. If you solely press the Enter key you would get the "Invalid..." message with the initial approach. To avoid the superflous message *and* sustain the behavior I mentioned you should read the unwanted `\n` with an additional `cin.get();`

Comment: @harper Ah, I see... However, adding the additional `cin.get()` would fix only that one case, and it would be redundant to write `cin.get()` in each case block. I just removed the first part about even trying to use `cin.get()` in this implementation because everything still breaks when you input `asdasd` or `2374`...

Comment: @harper Ah, sorry about that, fixed it. I did not see that he only was going to have five options, my apologies. Still, using `cin >>` is shorter and adds to readability..

Answer (score 0):

The enter key '\n' should be handled. Try following and see if it works:

```
while ((choice = cin.get()) != EOF)
{
  case 1:
  // ...
  // Basic idea is read extra `\n` and ignore it. Use below if condition
  default:
        if(choice != '\n')
          cout << "Invalid input. Re-Enter your selection: " << endl;
}
```

Comment: This way solved my problem but the loop doesn't work. Any idea how?

Comment: Basic idea is read `\n` and ignore it. I just updated the code by moving condition `if (choice != '\n')` inside the default code block.